# How do I combine a Controlled Lifetime relationship type (i.e. Owned<T>) with a delegate factory?

Tags: autofac

In my application, I have a service that requires a constructor parameter not resolved by Autofac, that I instantiate using a delegate factory:

```cs
public class Service
{
    public Service(string parameter /*, ... other dependencies */)
    {
    }

    public delegate Service Factory(string parameter);
}
```

This works great! I really love this feature.

I also like the Controlled Lifetime relationship, so I can let my component depend on a `Func<Owned<ISomething>>` like this:

```cs
public class Component
{
    private Func<Owned<ISomething>> _somethingFactory;

    /* constructor omitted for brevity */

    public void DoSomethingUseful()
    {
       using (var ownedSomething = _somethingFactory())
       {
           /* Lots of useful code here */
       }
    }
}
```

My problem is that now I want to combine the two. I can't have an instance of `Func<Owned<Service>>` injected, because it needs that parameter, so my current solution is to abstract the factory away into another service, say `IServiceFactory`:

```cs
public interface IServiceFactory
{
    Service Create(string parameter);
}
```

...implemented as such:

```cs
public class ServiceFactory : IServiceFactory
{
    private Service.Factory _internalFactory;

    public ServiceFactory(Service.Factory internalFactory)
    {
        _internalFactory = internalFactory;
    }

    public Service Create(string parameter)
    {
        return _internalFactory(parameter);
    }
}
```

My component then becomes this:

```cs
public class Component
{
    Func<Owned<IServiceFactory>> _serviceFactoryFactory;

    /* ... */ 
}
```

The need for such a field name leaves a bad taste in my mouth to the point that I suspect there must be a cleaner way to handle this case.

Is there another way?

Comment: Actually, I don't need the `IServiceFactory` as I can depend on a `Func<Owned<Service.Factory>>`, but still, that's a factory of factories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your injected factory to include the string parameter:

```
private Func<string, Owned<ISomething>> _somethingFactory;
```

Then you can pass the `string` to the factory when you want to create a new instance:

```
public void DoSomethingUseful()
{
   using (var ownedSomething = _somethingFactory("my parameter"))
   {
       /* Lots of useful code here */
   }
}
```

I've created a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6fo4NP) with a small working sample.

Comment: Ow nice :) didn't know I could do that.

Comment: This only works if there's only a single parameter of that type, like `string` in my case, right? I'm reading about Parameterized Instantiation: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#parameterized-instantiation-func-x-y-b

Comment: Yes unfortunately this is the case. However, to pass more than one `string` you could for example simply use a `string` array as parameter, but that's obviously not as nice as having separate parameters.

Comment: It's really not a problem in my case, I just wanted to point it out for future reference.